# Waiting for a signal by wrapping QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt5.2.0, I'm trying to write a `waitForSignal` function that accepts some of the same arguments as `QObject::connect`. It should make a connection one time, wait for the signal to occur, then disconnect the signal and return. Here's what I have so far (doesn't compile):

```
static void waitForSignal(
    const QObject *sender,
    const QMetaMethod &signal)
{
    QWaitCondition condition;
    QMutex mutex;

    QMetaObject::Connection conn =
    QObject::connect(sender, signal, nullptr, [&condition, &mutex]() -> void
    {
        mutex.lock();
        condition.wakeOne();
        mutex.unlock();
    });

    mutex.lock();
    condition.wait(&mutex);
    QObject::disconnect(conn);
}
```

It should be called like this:

```
class A;

class Q : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void someSignal(A &a);
}

waitForSignal(obj, &Q::someSignal);
```

I do not want to use the `SIGNAL` macro (and consequently make the second argument of `waitForSignal` to be `const char *`) because it can fail at runtime if the signature of the signal changes.

How do I accept the same type of argument that `QObject::connect()` accepts as it's second argument when I pass `&Q::someSignal`?

Comment: The obvious solution would be to copy-paste from Qt headers :)

Comment: @KubaOber the other question (how to properly wait) is not answered by the dupe.

Comment: @ratchetfreak "how to properly wait" - what do you mean by that? If you want a blocking wait, for some perverse reason, then a blocking wait you get...

Comment: @KubaOber I was in the middle of explaining that it should be written async and the option of processEvent if it was too much trouble.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Your answer belongs in that other question. For some reason they are really identical. Everyone seems to wish to "wait" for a signal, while missing the obvious that it's all handled by connecting a slot to the signal.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for finding the dupe. Somehow I missed it!

Comment: @KubaOber Regarding usage, the fact that there is an asynchronous signal in another thread is an implementation detail. The consumer of my function is synchronous, hence the `wait`.